# adding a **kwarg to a class

Tags: python, django

```
class StatusForm(ModelForm):

    bases = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=Base.objects.all(),  #this should get overwritten
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
        )

    class Meta:
        model = HiringStatus
        exclude = ('company', 'date')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StatusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.has_key('bases_queryset'):
            self.fields['bases'].queryset = kwargs['bases_queryset']
```

I want to add an option to this form that allows me to create a form like so:

```
form = StatusForm(bases_queryset=Base.objects.filter([...])
```

But I somehow need to "add" that keyword argument to the class so it will be recognized. They way it is now, I just get this error:

**`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bases_queryset'`**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because you're unpacking kwargs to the super constructor.
Try to put this before calling super:

```
if kwargs.has_key('bases_queryset'):
    bases_queryset = kwargs['bases_queryset']
    del kwargs['bases_queryset']
```

but it's not an ideal solution...

Comment: A better approach is simply:

bases_queryset = kwargs.pop('bases_queryset', None)

This removes the key from the dictionary and gives you its value, if it existed there, and also initializes to None when the key wasn't there.

Answer (score 11):

As @Keeper indicates, you must not pass your "new" keyword arguments to the superclass. Best may be to do, before you call super's `__init__`:

```
bqs = kwargs.pop('bases_queryset', None)
```

and after that `__init__` call, check `if bqs is not None:` instead of using `has_key` (and use `bqs` instead of `kwargs['bases_queryset']`, of course).

An interesting alternative approach is to make a "selective call" higher-order function. It's a bit of a mess if you have both positional and named arguments (that's *always* a bit messy to metaprogram around;-), so for simplicity of exposition assume the function you want to selectively call only has "normal" named arguments (i.e. no `**k` either). Now:

```
import inspect

def selective_call(func, **kwargs):
    names, _, _, _ = inspect.getargspec(func)
    usable_kwargs = dict((k,kwargs[k]) for k in names if k in kwargs)
    return func(**usable_kwargs)
```

with this approach, in your `__init__`, instead of calling super's `__init__` directly, you'd call
`selective_call(super_init, **kwargs)` and let this higher-order function do the needed "pruning". (Of course, you *will* need to make it messier to handle both positional and named args, ah well...!-)