# django model __init__ additional kwarg and handling if kwarg is wrong type

Tags: django, django-models

Per [adding a **kwarg to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987237/adding-a-kwarg-to-a-class)
I'm on the right track for converting cn__domainname to cn.
Am I on the right track for the case 'cn' is an integer or a string converting it to a domainname instance first, or should I do this in a validator?

```
class DomainName(models.Model):
    domainname = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True,
            validators=[DomainNameValidator])
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: domainname=%s' % ( self._meta.object_name, 
                self.domainname.__repr__())

class Machine(models.Model):
    cn = models.OneToOneField(DomainName, primary_key=True)
    #...
    ips = models.ManyToManyField(IP)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: cn=%s' % (self._meta.object_name, self.cn.domainname)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cn__domainname=kwargs.pop('cn__domainname',None)
        cn=kwargs.pop('cn',cn__domainname)
        if cn:
            if isinstance(cn,DomainName):
                kwargs['cn']=cn
            elif isinstance(cn,int):
                kwargs['cn']=DomainName.objects.get(id=cn)
            elif isinstance(cn,(str,unicode)):
                kwargs['cn']=DomainName.objects.get_or_create(domainname=cn)[0]
        super(Machine,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The goal is to be able to do

```
m,created=Machine.objects.get_or_create(cn__domainname='foo')
```

instead of

```
m,created=Machine.objects.get_or_create(
    cn__domainname='foo',
    defaults=dict(cn=DomainName.objects.get_or_create(domainname='foo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think at your Machine model, in the `__init__` method I will check like this:

```
 if getattr(self.cn, 'domainname'):
```

Anyway, looks messy.

What about using signals? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals

When creating a Machine record trigger the creation of a Domain record. Also, checking if integer or string for Domain should be on Domain.

To answer your question, in my opinion you are not in the *djangoist* path.